# Zoom in map different for city vs country android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I use below code to search on google map android

```
// An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service
    private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

        @Override
        protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
            // Creating an instance of Geocoder class

            Log.d("bagibagi","doInBackground");
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
            List<Address> addresses = null;

            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
            return addresses;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {         

            Log.d("bagibagi","onPostExecute");
            search = "";
            if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found OR you use this several time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {

                // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
                for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){                

                    Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

                    // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
                    latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());


                    String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                            address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                            address.getCountryName());


                    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    //markerOptions.icon(icon);
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    markerOptions.title(addressText);

                    //map.addMarker(markerOptions);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), addressText, 1).show();

                    // Locate the first location

                    if(i==0){
                        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(latLng)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
                        .zoom(13) 
                        // Sets the zoom
                        //.bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                        //.tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                        .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                    }   
                }   
            }


        }       
    }
```

how i can change `.zoom(13)` for a city search or a Country name search.
for example when user search a country map must zoom smaller than search a city.

**below image show you thing that i want.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Google Places API to obtain the Viewport of particular place.

1. Make request to this url: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=YOUR-COUNTRY-OR-CITY&sensor=true
2. In the JSON response you will find the following keys:

```
 geometry:{
      bounds:{
         northeast:{
            lat:40.501368,
            lng:-79.8657231
         },
         southwest:{
            lat:40.3613689,
            lng:-80.0952779
         }
      },
      location:{
         lat:40.44062479999999,
         lng:-79.9958864
      },
      location_type:"APPROXIMATE",
      viewport:{
         northeast:{
            lat:40.501368,
            lng:-79.8657231
         },
         southwest:{
            lat:40.3613689,
            lng:-80.0952779
         }
      }
   }
```

1. Either go for "geometry" key data or "viewport"
2. Create `new LatLngBounds (LatLng southwestParsedCoordinate, LatLng northeastParsedCoordinate)` object and move the camera to the that bound object
   `mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 10);`